# What make's a dylib different from another one?

Tags: c++, macos, dylib, dyld

I'm playing with dylib multiple loads and try to understand what makes the symbols differents.

Here are my steps:

- Build lib_a.dylib with the following entry point:

  ```
  FactoryA : IFActory () {}
  extern "C" IFactory* GetFactory () { return new FactoryA(); }
  ```
- Copy lib_a.dylib to lib_b.dylib
- Load GetFactory from lib_a.dylib and lib_b.dylib

  ```
  void * module=dlopen(fileName,RTLD_LAZY);
  void * proc = (void *)dlsym(module, "GetFactory");
  ```

When loading the second dylib (lib_b.dylib), GetFactory is considered as already defined by lib_a.dylib.
Effectively, nm output has the same result.

But I thought the compilation tag -two_level_namespace garantee that the 2 dylib are in a kind of different namespace, am I wrong ?

What could I change to have my two dylib loaded ?

---

Below is my test.

myclass.h :

```
#include <stdio.h>  
class IFactory {  
public:  
    virtual int GetCount() = 0;  
};  
extern "C"  
{
    extern IFactory* GetFactory ();
}
```

myclass.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "myclass.h"

class MyFactory : public IFactory {
public:
    virtual int GetCount() { mCount++; return mCount; }
    static int mCount;
};
int MyFactory::mCount = 0;


IFactory* GetFactory () {
    return new MyFactory;
}
```

mytest.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <mach-o/dyld.h>
#include "myclass.h"

typedef IFactory* (*factoryPtr)();

int main()
{  
    void* handleA = dlopen("libmylib.dylib", RTLD_LAZY);
    factoryPtr functionA = (IFactory*(*)())dlsym(handleA, "GetFactory");
    IFactory*  factoryA = (*functionA)();
    fprintf(stderr, "Handle A: %p\tFunction A: %p\t Count: %d\n", handleA, functionA, factoryA->GetCount());

    // Reload same library
    void* handleB = dlopen("libmylib.dylib", RTLD_LAZY);
    factoryPtr functionB = (IFactory*(*)())dlsym(handleB, "GetFactory");
    IFactory*  factoryB = (*functionB)();
    fprintf(stderr, "Handle B: %p\tFunction B: %p\t Count: %d\n", handleB, functionB, factoryB->GetCount());

    // Load copy of first library (just rename)
    void* handleC = dlopen("libmylib_copy.dylib", RTLD_LAZY);
    factoryPtr functionC = (IFactory*(*)())dlsym(handleC, "GetFactory");
    IFactory*  factoryC = (*functionC)();
    fprintf(stderr, "Handle C: %p\tFunction C: %p\t Count: %d\n", handleC, functionC, factoryC->GetCount());

    return 0;
}
```

Command :

```
clang++ -dynamiclib myclass.cpp -o libmylib.dylib  
cp libmylib.dylib libmylib_copy.dylib  
clang++ mytest.cpp -o mytest  
./mytest
```

Output :

```
Handle A: 0x7fe5dac039b0    Function A: 0x106d49d30  Count: 1    
Handle B: 0x7fe5dac039b0    Function B: 0x106d49d30  Count: 2    
Handle C: 0x7fe5dac03e00    Function C: 0x106d7cd30  Count: 3
```

Why do we have count = 3 at the end ?

---

The attribute -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden allow to do the same.

Modified myclass.h :

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#define EXPORT_FACTORY  __attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))
class IFactory {  
public:  
    virtual int GetCount() = 0;  
};   
extern "C"  
{
    extern EXPORT_FACTORY IFactory* GetFactory ();
}
```

Build :

```
clang++ -dynamiclib myclass.cpp  -o libmylib.dylib  -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden
cp libmylib.dylib libmylib_copy.dylib
clang++ mytest.cpp -o mytest
./mytest
```

Output :

```
Handle A: 0x7fe078c039b0    Function A: 0x1076e1c00  Count: 1
Handle B: 0x7fe078c039b0    Function B: 0x1076e1c00  Count: 2  
Handle C: 0x7fe078c03e20    Function C: 0x107714c00  Count: 1
```

Comment: After calling dlopen on both dylibs, if you use dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "GetFactory") and call it twice, do you get the two functions returned?

Comment: I get the following error    ERROR : dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,GetProcessorFactory): symbol not found

Comment: Could you add the relevant code to your question?

Comment: Thanks for adding that extra detail. That was sufficient to understand what is going on!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying issue here is the visibility of the symbols within your library. You can see via `nm -m` that there are several external symbols besides the `GetFactory` function you intend to export:

```
$ nm -m libmylib.dylib
0000000000000f30 (__TEXT,__text) external _GetFactory
0000000000001068 (__DATA,__common) external __ZN9MyFactory6mCountE
0000000000000f50 (__TEXT,__text) weak external __ZN9MyFactory8GetCountEv
0000000000001038 (__DATA,__data) weak external __ZTI8IFactory
0000000000001050 (__DATA,__data) weak external __ZTI9MyFactory
0000000000000f91 (__TEXT,__const) weak external __ZTS8IFactory
0000000000000f86 (__TEXT,__const) weak external __ZTS9MyFactory
0000000000001020 (__DATA,__data) weak external __ZTV9MyFactory
                 (undefined) external __ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE (from libc++)
                 (undefined) external __ZTVN10__cxxabiv120__si_class_type_infoE (from libc++)
                 (undefined) weak external __Znwm (from libc++)
                 (undefined) external dyld_stub_binder (from libSystem)
```

It is the symbols marked as `weak external` that are the cause of your problem.

Running your test application with `DYLD_PRINT_BINDINGS=YES` reveals:

```
$ DYLD_PRINT_BINDINGS=YES ./mytest
[ … output showing initialization of libstdc++.dylib and libmylib.dylib omitted …]
Handle A: 0x7fc729c03810    Function A: 0x102a51ee0  Count: 1
Handle B: 0x7fc729c03810    Function B: 0x102a51ee0  Count: 2
dyld: bind: libmylib_copy.dylib:0x102A85038 = libc++abi.dylib:__ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE, *0x102A85038 = 0x7FFF7CA67B50 + 16
dyld: bind: libmylib_copy.dylib:0x102A85050 = libc++abi.dylib:__ZTVN10__cxxabiv120__si_class_type_infoE, *0x102A85050 = 0x7FFF7CA67BD0 + 16
dyld: bind: libmylib_copy.dylib:0x102A85018 = libstdc++.6.dylib:__Znwm, *0x102A85018 = 0x7FFF938F0325
dyld: bind: libmylib_copy.dylib:0x102A85000 = libdyld.dylib:dyld_stub_binder, *0x102A85000 = 0x7FFF9084E878
dyld: weak bind: libmylib_copy.dylib:0x102A85030 = libmylib.dylib:__ZN9MyFactory8GetCountEv, *0x102A85030 = 0x102A51F00
dyld: weak bind: libmylib_copy.dylib:0x102A85060 = libmylib.dylib:__ZTI8IFactory, *0x102A85060 = 0x102A52038
dyld: weak bind: libmylib_copy.dylib:0x102A85028 = libmylib.dylib:__ZTI9MyFactory, *0x102A85028 = 0x102A52050
dyld: weak bind: libmylib_copy.dylib:0x102A85040 = libmylib.dylib:__ZTS8IFactory, *0x102A85040 = 0x102A51F41
dyld: weak bind: libmylib_copy.dylib:0x102A85058 = libmylib.dylib:__ZTS9MyFactory, *0x102A85058 = 0x102A51F36
dyld: weak bind: libmylib_copy.dylib:0x102A85010 = libmylib.dylib:__ZTV9MyFactory, *0x102A85010 = 0x102A52020
dyld: weak bind: libmylib_copy.dylib:0x102A85018 = libstdc++.6.dylib:__Znwm, *0x102A85018 = 0x7FFF938F0325
Handle C: 0x7fc729c03c20    Function C: 0x102a84ee0  Count: 3
```

If you look at the `weak bind` lines you'll see that the symbols we saw earlier that were marked as `weak external` are being resolved to the symbols of the same name in `libmylib.dylib`. I believe that this behavior relates to C++'s One Definition Rule ("Every program shall contain exactly one definition of every non-inline function or object that is used in that program"). Since you have multiple definitions of the same non-inline function in your program, the linker is attempting to coalesce the symbols at load time so only a single function is used.

The best solution here would be for each library to place its symbols inside a different namespace. Since you intend to export only C factory function, an anonymous namespace would be sufficient. This also has the effect of marking the remainder of the symbols as being non-external, which can be beneficial for library load time.

Alternatively, you can cheat a little bit on the One Definition Rule by only exporting the symbols that the clients of your library need:

```
$ clang++ -Wl,-exported_symbol -Wl,_GetFactory -dynamiclib myclass.cpp -o libmylib.dylib
$ cp libmylib.dylib libmylib_copy.dylib  
$ ./mytest
Handle A: 0x7fc593403910    Function A: 0x1009e4e90  Count: 1
Handle B: 0x7fc593403910    Function B: 0x1009e4e90  Count: 2
Handle C: 0x7fc593403b10    Function C: 0x1009e7e90  Count: 1
```

This causes the `weak external` symbols that we saw earlier to be marked as private, and therefore they will only resolve to symbols within the same image.

Comment: Compiling with "-fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden" option do the same and set the symbol as non-external (private external)

Comment: Yup, that's just another way of controlling which symbols are exported, like `-Wl,-exported_symbol` in my example.